# How to deliver work and procedure for freelancing in Android app development

Tags: payments, programmer, clients

When freelancing in android app development, what is the best way to work with the client(employer):

1) Should one deliver work and take payment in parts. Do clients pay in advance?

2) Whose credentials(email id, website) should be used when creating package name or using firebase.

3) What is the best way to share the UX of the app with the client. Is there any way to take the screenshot or display the UX like graphic designers do.

4) If the client wants to see the app before final payment. How to provide the app yet hold the full code.

5) What to deliver to the clients after the full payment (full project file, apk,source code). I use Android Studio 3.1.4

6) How to provide the final code to the clients. Is it possible to email the client on gmail or on internal inbox of freelance website. How to email the final code.

7) If the client wants to upload on playstore then whose account/ credentials should be used - clients or developer?

8) Is freelancer, upwork good for finding app work. How to find genuine clients?

9) Is it necessary to have own website or company name registered for freelance app developers?

Comment: You would be better served by narrowing your questions down to one topic rather than a catch-all for anything and everything related to freelancing. In addition, *many* of these questions may already have answers here if you use the search feature.

Answer (score 2):

> If the client wants to see the app before final payment. How to provide the app yet hold the full code.

I would build a beta build and send it to the client.

> How to provide the final code to the clients. Is it possible to email the client on gmail or on internal inbox of freelance website. How to email the final code.

Github or email is ok. Please communicate with the client.

> Is freelancer, upwork good for finding app work. How to find genuine clients?

Genuine? What do you mean? Upwork guarantees your payment as long as you do the works. If you mean, good and high paying clients, then NO. You need your connections.

> Is it necessary to have own website or company name registered for freelance app developers

No

> Should one deliver work and take payment in parts. Do clients pay in advance?

On Upworks, clients must pay for at least the first milestone. Whether doing in parts or full is not your decision.